# Using spinner OnItemSelectedListener() to start new intent

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner and when the user selects I want to call another java class using new Intent. The code below worked when I was using a Button but now I have it attached to the Spinner select I think it has something to do with view.getContext();

areaspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            int item = areaspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

       Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShowXMLPAR.class);
       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }

});
```

Can anyone help me update this part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right rather then view.getContext(0 you need reference to your Activity that has this spinner

example

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity,this, ShowXMLPAR.class);

Comment: Great that fixed the error. But now when the app loads it goes right into the ShowXMLPAR.class. without the Spinner being interated with. Do I need to add and if statement so that it does nothing until the default value of the spinner has changed? I may start a new post. thanks for your HELP!